# differentiating a polynomial interpolated set of data points

Tags: python, numpy

I'm aware that we can us `numpy` to differentiate polynomials with the following:

```
f = numpy.poly1d([1, 0, 1])
f.deriv()
```

I've tried interpolating a set of data points and performing `deriv()` on the resulting polynomial.

```
from scipy import interpolate

x = [-2,-1,2]
y = [-2,1,-1] 

f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y)
f.deriv()
```

But the object `f` is of different type.

Basically, how might I convert `f` to a `numpy` polynomial object ready for differentiation?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you interpolate you can set the level of polynomial of the spline. Typically one would stop at 2nd order, since you want to connect smoothly and have a smooth 1st derivative. For more, you'd need more than 3 points anyway. What is the application of finding the 1st derivative of the interpolated data? With measured (noisy) values it can be very risky to interpret that w/o further smoothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you're facing here is the way the interpolation actually works. Interpolation can at most guess some local function that matches the given points the best, but it can't exactly, and probably never is, except for perhaps some extreme easy cases(?), be exactly correct as the actual function given.

That said, you can approximate a function in a given range as a Taylor polynomial to a good degree. This should for relatively narrow ranges and a good guess of the initial function work sufficiently well for you.(?)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

x = [-2, -1, 2]
y = [-2, 1, -1]

f  = interpolate.interp1d(x, y)
h = interpolate.approximate_taylor_polynomial(f, -1, 2, 2)

h
>>>> poly1d([-0.61111111,  1.16666667, -0.22222222])

h.deriv()
>>>> poly1d([-1.22222222,  1.16666667])
```

**EDIT I Expanding the original answer for clarification:**

I wanted to show that this approach works to a point. The above OP example used is really small MWE example and thus the results are less than convincing.

To show it's fairly close approximation I'll construct a polynomial. I'll get its values in range [-5, 5]. I'll use the range [-5, 5] and the returned values of polynomial in as interpolation arrays.

I'll approximate the interpolated function with the Taylor series expansion using the best "guesses" I have (since I constructed the original polynomial this is not really a guess tbh).

I'll compare the results in range [-5, 5] from the Taylor expansion with the original polynomial values in the range.

```
f = np.poly1d([1,0,1])

f([-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> array([26, 17, 10,  5,  2,  1,  2,  5, 10, 17, 26])

x = [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [26, 17, 10,  5,  2,  1,  2,  5, 10, 17, 26]

f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y)

h = interpolate.approximate_taylor_polynomial(f, 0, 2, 5)

h(x)
>>> [26., 17.12, 10.21333333, 5.28, 2.32, 1.33333333, 2.32, 5.28, 10.21333333, 17.12, 26.]

f(x)
>>> [26., 17., 10., 5., 2., 1., 2., 5., 10., 17., 26.]
```

Here are some examples to show how the guesses get better and better the higher order of Taylor expansion you use. Careful as the manual says the expansion is unstable once it reaches order of 30.

```
h = interpolate.approximate_taylor_polynomial(f, 0, 15, 5)
>>> [ 25.41043927,  17.18570392,  10.19122784,   5.09107466,
         2.02363911,   1.        ,   2.02664952,   5.07915194,
        10.22646919,  17.13871545,  26.        ])

h = interpolate.approximate_taylor_polynomial(f, 0, 20, 5)
>>> [  26.        ,  17.13481942,  10.10070835,   5.21247548,
         2.13174692,   1.23098041,   2.13174692,   5.21247548,
        10.10070835,  17.13481942,  25.9999999 ])
```

**EDIT II Answers for questions in comments:**

It's not a stupid question. I can see that Taylor series is confusing you. In math they usually show the mathematical definition for the Taylor series based on nth order derivatives of the original function in the point of expansion but don't show others so it might be confusing as how to apply it in a broader sense.

In essence it's the same as with derivatives:

```
f' = lim d->0 [ ( f(x+d)-f(x) )/d ]
```

which in numerical programing we just approximate with:

```
f' = f(x+d)-f(x)/d (there are other approx of the derivative as well)
```

and that's an ok approximation as long as the d remains really small. Taylor series of a function goes something like this:

```
0th order: h ~ f(a) 
1st order: h ~ f(a) + f'(a)(x-a)
2nd order: h ~ f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + f''(a)/2 * (x-a)^2 ...
...
```

so if we now introduce our derivative approximation into the series expansion:

```
               1st deriv                        2nd deriv
h ~ f(a) + [ (f(a+d)-f(a))/d ] (x-a) + [ ( f(a+d) - 2f(a) + f(a-d) )/d^2 ) ] * (x-a)^2 ....
```

so now you see why the function needs the point in which it needs to be evaluated. Now, this helps us only to get rid of the derivation of the original function we had.

So you see, we don't need to know the original function at all. All we have to be able to do is provide approximated values the original function would have had in the point of expansion. And that is exactly what interpolation gives you.

Interpolation takes in a set of points presumably attributed to some original function and then based on the behavior of those points tries to guess which points in between the given points would most likely be in the graph of the original function as well. So in an essence, interpolation tries to guess the values of would-be function whose original points we know, within the range of those original points.

Ok. But what do we do about the fact that Taylor exp. goes into infinity? 
We just round it of:

```
h ~ 0th + 1st + 2nd + 3rd + ... + nth + P
```

and we call P the remainder. There are ways of estimating this remainder, some given by Taylor himself iirc.

Ok, but now why do we need a range in our function call?

What we did here is what's called a finite difference method. In essence it is just about as simple as that, in reality things can get a bit more complicated because you have to show that indeed you can do these things and not break the convergence of Taylor series. It turns out that you don't break the Taylor series BUT only for bounded continuous functions, which means that you can only approx functions on a certain interval.

Think of it this way. You can approximate a straight line with a Taylor series. Think of it as compounding more and more and more polynomial orders until their "waviness" cancels each other out. Like doing sin^2 + cos^2 which is always 1.

But if you stop the series expansion at some order, then suddenly you don't have anything stopping the series from diverging again. Because Taylor series is just one big polynomial it will either start going up into infinity or down into infinity. Look at the image bellow, it shows Taylor series approximating the original quadratic function `f` in the point of expansion 0 on a range of 10 around it; but plotted from -50 to 50.

[image]

Special interest is the 1st series order, which is just a straight line as you can see from the formulas above (green). Notice how as soon as the series cross -10 or 10 they start diverging from the actual function by a lot. In some cases the functions were similar enough to continue being close in value with the original function (i.e. 2nd order Taylor series is also a quadratic equation which is why it traces the original function very well).

Unfortunately because we do not have any prior knowledge about the original function in your case it's impossible to determine that some Taylor expansion estimates it perfectly. As far as we know we only approximated the function around 0. It might as well contain sine or cosine members for all we know.

As far as your question about f is concerned:

`f` is just some dummy function I started from. It's supposed to look like `np.poly1d([1,0,1])` which is supposed to be something like `f(x) = x**2 +1`. I don't know where you got `2.1667 + 0.25x - 0.9167x**2` from.

I used `f` just to create `x` and `y` arrays, so that I can be sure that indeed those numbers belong to a function. What would be the point otherwise. I only used it once more in the end by doing `f(x)` to show how similar the numbers turn out.

Remember `x` is an array, and `f(x)` means "calculate the value of function f for every member of array x". Nothing more. It's just the value of the function `f(x) = x**2+1` in the points `[-5, -4, .... 4, 5]`.

All other works was just based on how to approximate a function by Taylor expansion when all you have is some fixed data set and no knowledge of the original function. And I showed that if you interpolate between the points and approximate the unknown function with Taylor expansion you can reconstruct a function that has meaningfully similar results on a bounded range of numbers x.

That approximated function is called `h` in my snippets and it looks something like:

```
h = 2.28194274e-08 + 5.37467022e-17 x - 1.98652602e-06 x^2 - 3.65181145e-15 x^3 + 7.38646849e-05 x^4 + 1.02224219e-13 x^5 + ... till 25th order would be reached
```

and to get its derivative in python all you would need to do is

```
h.deriv()
```

because its type is poly1d.

Comment: The smallest polynomial which passes through all points will have highest degree equal to the number of data points provided. Of course we'll never know the exact function we want but shouldn't that be considered a perfect estimate? Is this what the taylor representation gives us? Basically, why must there be a specified range? See Vandermonde system.

Comment: @GregPeckory; I was writing the edit as you posted so look at it as well. In general you can fit an polynomial of n-1 degree that passes through n points **exactly** (so straight through (-5, 26) i.e. which is the original function as well). But I fail to see why that means the estimate is perfect? In general the behaviour of the function will be more closely approximated as the order n of Taylor expansion hrows to infinity.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer! This might be a stupid question, but to create a taylor polynomial, don't we need the original function and then we differentiate for each degree etc? In the above case we have `f`. What exactly is `f`? Is it `2.1667 + 0.25x - 0.9167x**2`? If this is the case can I differentiate this?

Comment: @GregPeckory; I've edited my answer further to answer all questions you had in these two comments as clearly as possible. I've also tried to explain in very brief short notes how in numerical Taylor expansion actually calculated. Hopefully this should cover all the basics. For anything more you're probably better off with a book on the topic of numerical programing and some basic knowledge of analytic functions, both real functions and holomorphic ones.

Comment: The 'extreme case' is when the sampling theorem is fulfilled. That is you have zero intensity in frequencies that exceed one half the sampling rate, which can be approximated with strong low pass filters. Then you can use a sum of sinc functions to interpolate `exactly`.

Comment: Wow, I can't thank you enough for this help. When I was talking about `f` I didn't mean `f = np.poly1d([1,0,1])`, I meant the code `f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y)`. The taylor polynomial is `h`, right? So to get `h` we must use the derivatives of `f` to get the taylor expansion. So, did you mean `h ~ f(a) + 1st deriv + ... `, instead of `f ~ f(a) + 1st deriv + ...`, because in that case we are using `f` to approximate `f`, which doesn't make sense to me. I'm really sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: @GregPeckory; Ah, that f. Well after the `f = interp1d` f becomes a interp1d class instance. Generally you can think of interpolation as a lot of functions each defined in between (bounded by) `[x_i, x_{i+1}]` where the `x`'s are the original given set of points. But the issue is that it's a `interp1d` class instance and you can't derive those.  And yes, I meant `h ~ f...`, I'll edit that in.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, you've taught me a lot, I really appreciate it!